# What is DiskCache in android, is it different from Physical harddisk space?

Tags: android, picasso, diskcache

Hi iam using a library called Picasso in android for displaying the images in a Recycer view, its saying that it will cace the images in diskcache, what is diskcache? can we see what files are stored in it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no much different in Memory Usage. However, if you using DiskCache, that means your cached images will be removed automatically when your app is uninstalled and no other app can touch your DiskCache images. With your Sdcard space, any1 can read/write into it.

Comment: Thank you, i am using a library called Picasso which is saving images in diskcache,  how do we know what is stored in DiskCache  programmatically?